# Access one field from another when using entities

Tags: entities, theming

On my Drupal 7 website, I have used Entity Construction Kit to create an entity that contains two fields: `field_body_image` and `field_image_position`.

This entity is then attached to a node.

I want to be able to access the value of `field_image_position` from inside `field_body_image`. How can I do this?

---

**Steps I have taken to solve the problem:**

I know that if you have the fields placed directly on the node (ie. so not using ECK) you can use [field_get_items](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52647/access-one-field-from-another-field-via-field-tpl-php)

However, this doesn't seem to work when ECK is involved.

Here is the code I am using in my template.php file

```
function [THEMENAME]_field__field_body_image(&$variables) {


    //Load the value of field_image_position
    $field_image_positon = field_get_items('node', $variables['element']['#object'], 'field_image_position');
    $image_positon       = $field_image_position['und'][0]['value'];

if ($image_positon == 'image_position_bottom' ) {
print 'Successful' //This is just a test to see if it works, the actual code will be different
}
 However, this does not work.
```

If I use Devel and do:

```
function [THEMENAME]_field__field_body_image(&$variables) {
kpr($field_image_positon);
}
```

Then I can see `field_image_position` located in the following:

```
$...['element']['#object']->field_image_position['und'][0]['value']
```

and

```
$...['element']['#items'][0]['value']
```

So how can I access it?

(using     `$field_image_positon = field_get_items('node', $variables['element']['#items'], 'field_image_position');` causes a White screen of Death. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned you are using ECK to create a new entity, whereas in your code, you are using `'node'` instead of the machine name of your entity.

I am referring to the line:

```
$field_image_positon = field_get_items('node', $variables['element']['#object'], 'field_image_position');
```

Change `node` in this line to `your_entity_machine_name`.